Measure of the sharpness of a peak
Let's say I have a function $g(r,t)$. To help visualize the problem, here are a few sample curves $g(r)_{|t=t_i}$, for a few different times $t_i$:

The $g(r)$ curves present a first sharp peak around $r=2.9A$. But my focus here is more on the secondary, broader peak in the $r=7A$ region.
As time goes by, this second peak tends to flatten slightly (note that the underlying process has a lot of noise so those samples might not reflect accurately the average trend, they're just here for illustration purposes). I would like a way to quantify this so that I could get a measure. Basically a flatness function of time $f(t)$ (or peakedness function $p(t)$), that could measure how sharp that second peak is at various moments of time and quantify its evolution.
However, when trying to search for such measurements, I get stuck with google stubbornly throwing kurtosis at me, even though it seems to be specially tailored for statistical distributions compared to the normal distribution (unless there is a generalization that I didn't find to general functions).
A naive approach would be to simply measure the maximum of the peak, but it doesn't seem like a solid way to capture the peakedness, especially on noisy data with a lot of local extrema. Another way would be to arbitrarily choose a region around the peak (say $r=6-8A) and calculate the kurtosis of those data points, but I doubt this is a standard way to make this kind of measurement.
Another possibility (suggested in comments), would be to fit the peak to a gaussian. We could then use the parameters of the gaussian as a measure of the flatness of the peak. It seems reasonable but I don't know if this is a standard approach. It also seems that both the height of the Belle curve as well as its standard deviation would be relevant to characterize the sharpness of a peak, and I'm not certain how to encapsulate it in one measure.
In short: What mathematical tool is there to quantitatively measure "how sharp" a peak is in a (noisy) curve?

Could you model this as a sum of two functions? (Eg Gaussians) Alternatively, you could just look at the function over time for $r>4A$.

@ChrisLewis Yes, separating the two peaks is not the problem, my question is more about finding a good way to quantitatively measure the sharpness of a peak.  From a modelling standpoint, I have no reason to assume a specific underlying function (gaussian or other). Are you suggesting to fit the relevant part of a curve to a gaussian and use the standard deviation as a measure of the flatness? Seems reasonable but I'm not sure if it's a very rigorous/standard way to address this. It seems that both the std and the "height" of the gaussian would be relvant to describe how sharp the peak is.

@BarbaudJulien What about computing the left and right derivatives at the peak abscissa? The absolute value of the slopes tell you how sharpe the peak is, and if the two limits coincide, then it tells you that your signal is smoother at that point.

In case anybody ends up here looking for a solution to a similar problem, I will post a self-answer with what I ended up doing. If you have any feedback/criticism or improvements on it, please do share them!
We are looking for a reasonable way to quantify the broadening of a peak over time (measuring the decrease of its "sharpness").
My solution was to compare it to a perfectly falt curve: a uniform curve taken at the average value of the peak. If it is close to the uniform curve, the peak is flat. The more difference, the sharper it is. So:

select the range of the curve that contains your peak
integrate to calculate the average value over that range
for every point, calculate the difference with the average
aggregate the results as a root mean square difference (RMSD)

Basically, if your peak is described by a set of data points $y_i...y_n$ of average value $\bar y$, I define the sharpness $S$ as:
$$S = \sum_{j=i}^{n}(y_j-\bar y)^2$$
This is essentially the variance of the data points in the range. But I prefer to think of it as the RMSD distance from a perfectly flat curve, which explains why it is a decent measure of sharpness. Here is the trend for the sharpness over time that I obtain in my case thanks to that definition (the time dependence obtained nicely fits the expected model, suggesting that the sharpness measure is coherent):

This is only intended to be used for the analysis of a reasonably well-defined peak.
